# Inserir dados no banco de dados MYSQL pelo PHP com mais de 1 tela

Tags: php, html

Eu tenho o meu index.php e consigo inserir dados no banco de dados utilizando formulário html, porém eu preciso de várias telas para esse formulário ou seja são 3 telas, index.php, tela2.php e tela3.php como eu faço para fazer só 1 inserção utilizando um botão submit no final de tudo na tela3.php mas pegando todos os campos das 3 telas e fazendo só 1 inserção como disse? estou utilizando o código abaixo porém ele só faz a inserção nos campos de formulário na mesma tela.

```
if(isset($_POST['acao'])){
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $sobrenome = $_POST['sobrenome'];
    $momento_registro = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `clientes` VALUES(null,?,?,?)");

    $sql->execute(array($nome,$sobrenome,$momento_registro));

    //echo 'Cliente inserido com sucesso!';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma das soluções, se você vai usar somente PHP por falta de conhecimento em outra tecnologia como Javascript para fazer isso sem dar refresh na página, seria criar um formulário para cada arquivo.

Na submissão do formulário, através de um input do tipo submit, você grava os dados em uma sessão e recupera todos estes dados na última tela.

E faz o insert enviado `$_SESSION['dados']` para o seu script de banco.

Faz um curso de MVC, não invista em código procedural porque já caiu em desuso. Aprendi a usar um Laravel da vida :)

Answer (score 0):

Dá uma olhadela aqui. https://codepen.io/piyushpd/pen/PooPByb e aqui https://bootsnipp.com/search?q=wizard .
Isto é um exemplo de um 'Wizard Form'. O codigo fica todo na sua tela1.php mas parece que tem varias paginas. Mesmo se não quiser usar um 'wizard form' penso que a unica maneira será guardar cada form em uma variavel de sessão e então depois na submissão do ultimo form acessar as variaveis que foi guardando enquanto ia submetendo os forms ''antigos''. Pesquise por ''wizard form'' e vai encontrar mais informação se precisar.

Answer (score 0):

Há duas formas de se fazer isso utilizando html e php nativo, a primeira delas é: Você pode passar os valores de um formulario para o outro e esconder os valores com o hidden, exemplo: 
e só fazer a inserção na tela3.
Ou pode fazer a inserção de valores no primeiro form, preencher os campos restantes com null, e na tela 2 e 3 fazer um update neste regristro